# Subplot of difference between data points imported with Pandas and conversion of time values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time, graph

I'm relatively new to Python (in the process of self-teaching) and so this is proving to be quite a learning curve but I'm very happy to get to grips with it. I have a set of data points from an experiment in excel, one column is time (with the format 00:00:00:000) and a second column is the measured parameter.

I'm using pandas to read the excel document in order to produce a graph from it with time along the x-axis and the measured variable along the y-axis. However, when I plot the data, the time column becomes the data point number (i.e. 00:00:00:000 - 00:05:40:454 becomes 0 - 2000) and I'm not sure why. Could anyone please advise how to rectify this?

Secondly, I'd like to produce a subplot that shows the difference between the y-values as a function of time, basically a gradient to show the variation. Is there a way to easily calculate this and display it using pandas?

Here is my code, please do forgive how basic it is!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab

df = pd.read_excel('rest.xlsx', 'Sheet1')

df.plot(legend=False, grid=False)

plt.show()
plt.savefig('myfig')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just read the excel file, pandas will create a RangeIndex, starting at 0. To use your time information from you excel file as index, you have to specify the name (as string) of the time column with the key-word argument index_col in the read_excel call:

```
df = pd.read_excel('rest.xlsx', 'Sheet1', index_col='name_of_time_column')
```

Just replace 'name_of_time_column' with the actual name of the column that contains the time information.
(Hopefully pandas will automatically parse the time information to a Datetimeindex, but your format should be fine.) The plot will use the Datetimeindex on x-axis.
To get the time difference between each datapoint, use the diff method with argument 1 on your DataFrame:

```
difference = df.diff(1)
difference.plot(legend=False, grid=False)
```

Comment: That's worked brilliantly, thank you so much! In addition to that, do you know how I can get the difference plot to be a subplot, such that both plots are on the same figure? The difference plot would ideally be below the main plot.

Comment: I posted the answer in an additonal response.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('rest.xlsx', 'Sheet1')


X = df['Time'].tolist()#If the time column  called 'Time'

Y = df['Parameter'].tolist()#If the Parameter column called 'Parameter'

plt.plot(X,Y)

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

With matplotlib you can create a figure with two axis and name the axis for example `ax_df` and `ax_diff`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, [ax_df, ax_diff] = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True)
```

`sharex=True` specifies to use the same x-axis for both subplots.

When calling plot on the DataFrame, you can redirect the output to the axis by specifying the axes with the keyword argument ax:

```
df.plot(ax=ax_df)
df.diff(1).plot(ax=ax_diff)
plt.show()
```